# Document management software for small office?

Tags: file-management, document-management

I want a document management software for a small office.

The system should be especially proficient in handling letters/document going in and out; all letters dispatched should have a slip to be signed by recipient at the time of receiving and then the slip should be attached back to the system as proof of delivery.

Requirements:

- The system should be able to control versioning
- Ability to manage users and access rights
- Should be in-house hostable - not cloudbased on another server

Optional files editing via the system.

Comment: http://docushare.xerox.com/ - Get out the chequebook. :)

Comment: What hardware will this live on? If you don't already own your own hardware, and you need to buy that too, you may want to look into a NAS. A good one is: Sycnology http://www.synology.com/en-us/ although I'm not sure it natively supported versioning. A colleague of mine at work has been researching a in-office replacement for Google Docs and this is what our team is looking at.

Comment: Are these physical paper letters/slips? Or digital ones? Are signatures done with a physical pen, or with a digital signature? If digital signature, do you already have any authentication solution in place, or a users management server like OpenLDAP?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider [Content Central](http://www.ademero.com/) by Ademero.

- Has version control
- Has the ability to manage users and access rights
- Is usually hosted in-house

Their website has a lot of good resources, including videos and brochures, but for a quick overview you can look at the [features list](http://www.ademero.com/products/features/).

Answer (score 0):

For a complete (Scan, Capture and Document Management) and affordable solution, look at Librex.

Covers your Version control, Access Rights and In-house requirements.

More info in this PDF: http://www.coriumsoft.com/images/stories/librex%20edms.pdf

You can install it by yourself here (or ask Corium for support): http://www.coriumsoft.com/confluence/display/librexEN/Librex+Quick+Start+Guide

Librex also offers a free version (with 30$ donation to Room to Read) for up to 2000 captured pages per year, and an Enterprise version for larger volumes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the below options for you to look at:

1. LogicalDOC
2. OpenKM
3. Afresco

Great platforms to work on. Also if you are also looking at hardware, like "J.T. McGuigan" suggested, take a look into Synology and their platform. I have it in my home and it is a complete solution for all office size works, just select the appropriate server.

I hope this helped. Cheers!

Links:

https://www.logicaldoc.com/

https://www.openkm.com/

https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5792-download-and-install-alfresco